# IS it safe to Delete .DAT and .DA5 Files in the Inteldata folder?

Tags: windows

So in my C:>ProgramData>Intel>SUR>QUEENCREEK>inteldata folder I have almost 6gbs of DAT and DA5 files. I desperately need to clear space in my C: Drive and I don't know where else to clear it from. I don't even know how it keeps filling up more and more when I save everything and download things to my other drive. So is it safe to delete these files or is there somewhere else I should look to clear space? most the file names are like "p011***.DAT" with the *'s being other numbers counting up. My DA5 file names are either temp_string_section, temp_sample_section, or w000000 counting up to 6000! (EX: w006000) which is such an insane number of small files. Thank you.

Comment: You need to determine what Intel software package you have installed that uses them, but files in the ProgramData directory, are not required for Windows to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I updated Intel Driver Update Utility and it cleared the folder for now. It seems to be temp files for my networking card.

Answer (score -1):

The running service that is writing these files is called Intel System Usage Report Service.

The program that uses the service is: Intel(R) Driver Update Utility

You can painlessly uninstall this, then check if the files got removed in the uninstall (should happen). If not, delete the files.

If you feel like you wanted that program, even though Windows Update should keep your Intel drivers up to date, you could install a more recent version of that program, called the Intel® Driver & Support Assistant.